# How to update an entry for which I have a cursor in android?

Tags: android

I have the following query which returns a single element (at most):

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(
            DATABASE_TABLE_SERIES,
            new String[]{KEY_PRICE},
            KEY_BOOK + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(bookId)},
            null,
            null,
            KEY_DATE+" ASC",
            "1"
    );
```

I might need to update this particular single entry in the database. Here is what I try:

```
ContentValues changedValues = new ContentValues();
changedValues.put(KEY_PRICE, changedPrice);
db.update(
    DATABASE_TABLE_SERIES, 
    changedValues, 
    "KEY_BOOK = ? ORDERBY "+ KEYDATE +" ASC LIMIT 1",
    new String[]{String.valueOf(bookId)}
);
```

which does not work (as I expected).

How can I update the exact entry that I query with the query result? I strongly would prefer some example code, as I probably will not understand an explanation in text-form (I am an android-beginner)!

Comment: remove the `OrderBy...` in the `Update()` function. it doesn't belong there.

Comment: This does not answer my question ...

Comment: well, you also need to be in a transaction (and COMMIT it) in order for the change to "stick". is that your issue?

Comment: I want to update the single, particular, sole, explicit, one database row-entry which I select in the select statement.

Comment: Your WHERE statement needs to be as specific as possible (is there an unique key?) such that it only effects one row.

Comment: "WHERE the KEYDATE is the smallest" This is my WHERE-statement (in prosa). I do not know how to convert this text-statement in a proper sql statement...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104201/discussion-between-alex-and-david-m).

Comment: Ah, I need to query the row id of that single entry. then i can update this particular row... I guess I have it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update this single entry, one must create a unique identifier. A unique identifier is the `id` in each table. So one must first `select` this unique identifier, then the remainder follows easily. Here is the example code:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(
        DATABASE_TABLE_SERIES,
        new String[]{'id'},
        KEY_BOOK + " = ?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(bookId)},
        null,
        null,
        KEY_DATE+" ASC",
        "1"
);
cursor.moveToFirst();

ContentValues changedValues = new ContentValues();
changedValues.put(KEY_PRICE, changedPrice);
db.update(
    DATABASE_TABLE_SERIES, 
    changedValues, 
    "id = ?",
    new String[]{cursor.getString(0)}
);
```

Of course, one could modify the first request to query both, the `price` and the `id` in one go, if that is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
"KEY_BOOK = ? ORDERBY "+ KEYDATE +" ASC LIMIT 1",
```

with:

```
"KEY_BOOK = ?",
```

There is no `ORDER BY` clause or `LIMIT` clause on [an `UPDATE` statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

Comment: But then I have multiple possible entries? I have hundreds of entries to which the query "KEY_BOOK=3" match. Are they all being updated? This is not what I want...

Comment: @Alex: "But then I have multiple possible entries?" -- then replace `KEY_BOOK` and the value with some unique identifier. We do not know your database schema; I had assumed that `KEY_BOOK` was actually a primary key.